# Null pointer in dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

This programe throws Null pointer execption.
here is my code.

```
    public void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    //adb.setTitle(this.mTitle);
    adb.setMessage(this.mBody);
    adb.setPositiveButton("YES", action);
    adb.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    adb.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome, to SO. Please tag the question (actually there is no question) with a programming language. Also, it would be helpful to indicate which line gives the error

Comment: Can you show that you have tried to solve your issue first?

Comment: I tried a lot but i am not getting what to change.... am getting the error at  AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

Comment: Mention your question clearly

Comment: So where is `mContext` initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code and as you mentioned in the comment.  I can say you are not initializing you mContext. If you are initializing your mContext Then Use this.mContext to initialize the context I think this will work for U.

Answer (score 0):

On which line are you receiving the NullPointerException?

From this code fragment alone, there is no reference to `action` in the YES button:

```
adb.setPositiveButton("YES", action);
```

The only way this could be valid is if `action` is defined outside of this method.